# Return inválido

Tags: java

Estoy intentando crear un método que devuelva un valor primo para una calculadora de primos en android java, pero al intentar crear el return me dice "cannot return a value from a method with void result type", pero a la vez me da el error "invalid method declaration, return type declared"
¿Cómo hago que me acepte el return, si es que se puede?

```
public getPrimo(){
    int primo = 2;
    int counter = 2;
    return primo;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int getPrimo(){
    int primo = 2;
    int counter = 2;
    return primo;
}
```

En java, tienes que especificarle el tipo de dato que vas a devolver.

Los 2 errores que te aparecen vienen dado por el mismo problema:

```
cannot return a value from a method with void result type
```

Aquí te dice que ha encontrado la palabra "return" y por tanto, debes especificar en tu función que tipo de dato tienes que devolver.

```
invalid method declaration, return type declared
```

Aquí igual, no se está declarando bien el método porque se necesita declarar lo que vas a devolver.